# Using list for different type of messages and assigning a

Tags: vb.net, message

My below code is working as print a messages about processes to richtextbox area in   my main form(GUI)

```
Public Class LogArea
    Public Shared Sub WriteMsg(ByVal ConsoleMsgType As String, ByVal ConsoleMsg As String)
        rtxtLogArea.AppendText(ConsoleMsgType & ":" & vbTab & ConsoleMsg & vbCrLf)
        rtxtLogArea.ScrollToCaret()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm using this in my other procedures and writing "INFO", "ERROR" or "WARNING" string parameter as ConsoleMsgTYpe and writing message as string `("400 - You exceed your limit" & upperLimit)` as ConsoleMsg .

Finally using it in my other modules like;

```
LogArea.WriteMsg("WARNING", "400 - You exceed your limit" & upperLimit)
```

'Outputs in richtextarea like below

> WARNING: You exceed your limit 20 Hz

I'd like to define an list for each of INFO, WARNING and ERROR type of my custom messages and get the message code and message from list.

```
LogArea.WriteMsg(w,wMsgList(400)) or similar logic
```

it will output the same

> WARNING: You exceed your limit 20 Hz

Comment: Can you transform the single string ("400 - You exceed your limit") to a Dictionary or a class object, where the Key or an Integer Property offer a way to identify the message by value? A Dictionary is probably better if you don't have, now or eventually, other attached values (like - since you're using a RichTextBox - different Colors to use for the different message types).

Comment: @Jimi thanks for the recommendation i don't have the dictinoary but it seems good to have one :). I don't have a color property but if i want at future it's hard to define ?

Comment: Implementing it, not at all. But you'ld have to transform your Dictionary from `Dictionary(Of Interger, String)` (Identifier and Text to show) to a `Dictionary(Of Integer, [Class])`, where `[Class]` is a specialized class that contains all the required properties of a specific message type. So, this is more a matter of design choices. Where you foresee the future requirement and (try to) minimize the possbile impact in case some of the requirements change.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for the helps, but i'd like to kindly ask you is it possible to text as an answer i can vote up and understand basics especially for the section -  "But you'ld have to transform your Dictionary from Dictionary(Of Interger, String) (Identifier and Text to show) to a Dictionary(Of Integer, [Class]), where [Class] is a specialized class that contains all the required properties of a specific message type."

Comment: Yes, sure, I can do that. Have you tested a solution with a Dictionary or something else that fits? If not, what properties should your Message object have? Just a reference code (`400`, in the example) and a Text which already includes the Alert Level (`WARNING`, here)? Or the Alert Level should be defined at run time? Does it have to show a related Bitmap? The Color of the Text, should it change based on the Alert Level? If you tell me what are the mandatory details your Log message should have, I can post an example.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use nested Classes with Shared Strings.

Perhaps something like this?

```
Public Class MainTool

    Private Sub MainTool_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LogArea.rtxtLogArea = Me.rtxtLogArea
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim limit As String = "20 Hz"
        LogArea.WriteMsg(Messages.Warning._400_Limit_Exceeded & limit)
        LogArea.WriteMsg(Messages.Info._100_Unicorn_Escaped)
        LogArea.WriteMsg(Messages.Errors._314_Pi)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class LogArea

    Public Shared rtxtLogArea As RichTextBox

    Public Shared Sub WriteMsg(ByVal ConsoleMsg As String)
        rtxtLogArea.AppendText(ConsoleMsg & vbCrLf)
        rtxtLogArea.ScrollToCaret()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Messages

    Public Class Info
        Public Shared _100_Unicorn_Escaped = "Info" & vbTab & "100 - The Unicorn has escaped."
        Public Shared _200_Llama_Hungry = "Info" & vbTab & "200 - The Llama is hungry."
    End Class

    Public Class Errors
        Public Shared _314_Pi As String = "Error" & vbTab & "3.14 - Somedbody ate all the Pie!"
        Public Shared _500_Missing_Parameter As String = "Error" & vbTab & "500 - Somedbody ate all the Pie!"
    End Class

    Public Class Warning
        Public Shared _400_Limit_Exceeded As String = "Warning " & vbTab & "400 - You exceeded your Limit "
        Public Shared _900_Space_Low As String = "Warning " & vbTab & "900 - Available Space is Low "
    End Class

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm only asking for robustness side; i've almost 100 messages in total and will it causing the bad performance declaring each of them as a variable.

Comment: Another option would be to put them all together in an ENUM.